# Implicitly defined object & Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Having some trouble with the Xml Serialization in .Net (again)...

Attached is the code (original working version at the top, new non-working version below) 
[image]

(Cast to Rental was added as a test - it fails with or without that cast)

The xml Deserialize fails for the implicitly defined object with the following error:

"There is an error in XML document (0,0)." 
"Root element is missing"

Any suggestions as to why I can't deserialize an implicitly declared object.  Seems like a logical thing to be able to do - what's the difference between an explicit and implicit object??

btw, if i do a rental.GetType(), it returns Rental (so it is the correct object type that is being instantiated).

Deserialization method looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Deserialize` method?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: It seems the `stream` content is a malformed XML, or the stream is not properly positioned.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why it works for the explicitly defined variable, and not for the implicit one, even on the same code run.  Even if i switch the order of them around.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following line to your `Deserialize` method just before deserialization.

```
if (stream.CanSeek) stream.Position = 0; // fix a possible positioning issue on the stream

var obj = s.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Nah that didn't fix it... throws a different error now though:

There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
<rental xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: Essentially, to my knowledge, there shoul be no difference between the object created by

var r = new Rental();

and:

Rental r = new Rental();

So why does the top one fail and the bottom one not fail?  There's nothing else different in the code beside the object instantiation.  Weird.

Comment: Humm... I suspect you are not flushing the serialization stream properly causing the XML to be truncated (malformed).

Comment: Still, why does it work for the explicity variable but not the implicit one?  what is different between them?

Comment: Can you invert the code?  so, `rrr` is deserialized first then `r`.  Does it change the outcome?

Comment: No, i tried that before.  if rrr.Deserialize is called before r.Deserialize, rrr fails and r succeeds.

Comment: I'm at a loss.  I tried your code locally and it just works.  I don't know what might be going wrong.

Comment: Me either wdosanjos... Truth is this project is fraught with weirdness  (i inherited it from another developer) and I'm just trying to finish it off so i can move onto something new. I've made a solution that's good enough for now, and have given up on solving this. Sometimes you have to just choose your battles, and in this case solving this problem is not my battle of choice.  haha

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed in a previous comment

> There is an error in XML document (1, 2). <**rental** xmlns=''>

<s>If the xml in the stream actually spells "rental" with a lower-case r, I don't know how *either* of these would ever work - it has to be "Rental" with capital R to match your type name. Maybe that's just a typo but I thought I'd point it out since your code otherwise should work.</s>
*Update: OP has explained that this is because of `[XmlType("rental")]` decoration on the class. So this is not the cause of the problem.*

Unless I'm gravely mistaken, there really is no difference in the compiled version of

```
Rental r = new Rental();
```

and

```
var r = new Rental();
```

Using an XML file `(D:\Rental2.txt)` like this:

```
<Rental>
<ID>10</ID>
</Rental>
```

This code will run in LinqPad and sucessfully deserialise both the explicit and implicit variables:

```
void Main()
{
    var sw = new StreamReader(@"d:\Rental2.txt");
    try
    {
        //explicit
        Rental r = new Rental();
        var Explicit = r.Deserialise(sw.BaseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(Explicit);

        //implicit
        var rrr = new Rental();
        var Implicit = rrr.Deserialise(sw.BaseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(Implicit);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    { 
        sw.Close();
    }
}

public class Rental
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

public static class Extensions
{
 public static T Deserialise<T>(this T Object,Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Position=0;
        }
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UserQuery+Rental 
ID 10 

UserQuery+Rental 
ID 10
```

Can you post the source data you are trying to deserialise from? Perhaps there is something quirky about it?

Comment: Thanks Stephen... Here's why the deserialization works with lowercase "rental"

 [Serializable]
 [XmlType("rental")]
 public class Rental : Property

As for the source data, I don't see why that would be an issue.. what is happening that is different between the explicitly defined object and the implicit one?  They're using the same data, one works one doesn't.  How can it be an issue with the data?

Comment: @Gregorius ok that's clear now. Actually I would be flabbergasted if it *was* an issue with the data! It's just that I can't see anything wrong with your code and there really should be 0 difference; The code I posted is functionally the same as your so I suppose we're clutching at straws right now :) I guess we need to take the reduction approach; start removing things until it works - for example, can you un-inherit from Property, un-decorate the class and try with a manual file. If this works for both approaches, then it eliminates the code itself, etc...

Comment: Hey Stephen,  Thanks for the ideas.  I've actually just come up with a solution that is close enough to what i was trying to achieve.  Instead of using implicit declaration, i'm using explicit, running the deserialiser on that, then setting the resulting object onto the implicit variable for use later.  It's not perfect but it's good enough.  I don't have time to keep digging into this, it's weird and i'd love to know why it's not working, but I have bigger fish to fry.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Gregorius - not at all, any time. Glad you have found a way to work around it! Comment here if you want to resurrect the issue sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@wdosanjos is right. If you are running the two `Deserialize` one by another, then try to reset the position of stream to 0 before `Deserialize` the second one.

```
Rental r = new Rental();
r = r.Deserialize(stream);

stream.Position = 0; // reset stream position.

var rrr = new Rental();
rrr = ((Rental)rrr).Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Nope that's not it.  If i run the implicitly declared one first, it will fail.  I'd need to reset the stream position to get the explicit one to work if trying to run it on the implicit one first, but that's beside the point.  The stream position is not the cause of this issue.